# How to rebuild local action

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I would like to add one action to a page (let's say the route `entity.node.canonical`) but this action would appear and disappear from the page time to time.

So what I'm trying to do is to create the action using a deriver (I put my condition to show the action in the method `getDerivativeDefinitions`) and then, on a kernel event, I refresh the local actions using `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.local_action')->clearCachedDefinitions();`

But it still doesn't work !

So is anybody capable of showing me a method to show and hide an action ?

Here is my derivative:

```
class ConditionalAction extends DeriverBase implements ContainerDeriverInterface {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition)
  {
    // If the seconds is more than 30, hide the action.
    if (date('s') > 30) {
      return $this->derivatives;
    }
    
    // Else, show the action.
    $menu_entry = $base_plugin_definition;
    $menu_entry['route_name'] = 'my.route.name';
    $menu_entry['title'] = 'Test action';
    $menu_entry['appears_on'][] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
    $menu_entry['route_parameters'] = ['time' => date('s')];

    $this->derivatives['my.action.name'] = $menu_entry;

    return $this->derivatives;
  }
}
```

And here is the event subscriber:

```
class MyModuleKernelSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest'
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Event called when a request is sent.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    // Do not consider the ajax requests.
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() === TRUE) {
      return;
    }

    // Flush local action cache.
    \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.local_action')->clearCachedDefinitions();
  }
}
```

So, here, on each request, the local action should be cleared and the code should go through my derivative. But it's not working... Any thought ?

I really need it to be an action ! And I really need the URL argument to be dynamic as well (here, `$menu_entry['route_parameters'] = ['time' => date('s')];`).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking inside the console command `drupal cache:reset`, I found that the lines

```
$bins = Cache::getBins();
$bins['render']->deleteAll();
$bins['discovery']->deleteAll();
```

reset the local actions on each requests.
So I have my answer now.

Hope this will help !